# Loading a package in cmake when migrating a linux project to visual studio

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I am importing a C++ project from Linux to Windows and want to run it by VS. There is a `CMakeList.txt` file, which specify package location on a linux environment.
I have downloaded same package in Window os and try to run the project.

CMakeList.txt on Linux was like this:

```
 set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /home/dnd/systemc-2.3.3) 
 find_package(SystemCLanguage CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

And I modified it to give package address:

```
 set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\systemc-2.3.3\\") 
 find_package(SystemCLanguage CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

It is still cannot find the package. What I am missing here?

Comment: Do not put absolute paths in your build scripts (in _any_ build system, not just CMake), ever. CMake provides [user-defined presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) for this purpose.

Comment: @AlexReinking Can you provide a link with an example. I get the idea, but need to see what are the other details in `CMakeUserPresets.json` file

Comment: We use presets in the Halide project to simplify packaging. https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/CMakePresets.json

Comment: Thanks, I guess I need to update `msvc-debug` or `package-windows` sections.

Answer (score 0):

Change path to: `C:/sytemc-2.3.3./`.